# convergence or divergence of $\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k k}{\sqrt{k^2+1}}$

Tags: calculus

> Finding whether the series $\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k\cdot k}{\sqrt{k^2+1}}$ converge or diverge.

What i try

Write it as

$$0+\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^kk}{\sqrt{k^2+1}}>\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^kk}{\sqrt{k^2+k^2}}=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}(-1)^k(\text{Diverge})$$ for all $k\geq 1$

So we can say that our series is diverge.

Is my reasoning is correct. If not How,do i solve it .help me please

Comment: you lost  a factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} $. Anyway it is correct

Comment: $\frac{{( - 1)^k k}}{{\sqrt {k^2  + 1} }} > \frac{{( - 1)^k k}}{{\sqrt {k^2  + k^2 } }}$ holds only if $k$ is even. For odd values of $k$, the inequality is reversed.

Comment: Thanks Gray. You are Right. I realise my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The series diverges, since you don't have $\lim_{k\to\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^kk}{\sqrt{k^2+1}}=0$.

You seem to be using the comparaison test, but that test is for series of non-negative numbers.

Comment: Thanks Hosr Carlos. But i did not understand why $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_{k}=0$. Can you please explain me.

Comment: I wrote that we *don't* have that.

Comment: You means $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}a_{k}=\pm 1(\neq 0).$ So series Diverge.

Comment: No. I mean that since the limit either doesn't exist or it exits but it is not $0$ (in this case, it doesn't exist), then the series diverges.

Comment: For a series to be convergent it in necessary that its terms tend to $0$. Thus, if the terms do not tend to $0$, the series cannot converge.

Comment: But when we take $k=2n$. Then limitvis $+1$ . When wectake $k=2n+1.$ Then limit is $-1$. So the limit is either $+1$ or $-1$

Comment: No. The conclusion is that it has no limit. No sequence has more than one limit.

Comment: So we can say that here limit does not exists. Because unique value is not obtained.Is am right

Comment: The terms DO NOT tend to zero hence the series cannot converge.

Comment: A better justification is: $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{2k}=1$ and $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{2k-1}=-1$. Therefore, there is no limit.

Comment: Thanku so much. I got it.